# Schema not loading in local environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I am a recent grad of a full stack bootcamp, working on an existing Ruby Rails project.  The problem I'm having is the database is not loading the schema. Ran:

- rake db:migrate
- rake db:schema:load

I see the schema load in the terminal with all of the seed data but does not load to my app on the local server. When I run rake db:migrate, I get this:

- A monkey patch for Ahoy::Store has been loaded from /Users/learnacademy/dev/gnomon-workshop/config/initializers/ahoy.rb

From what I've found online says a gem was installed by another developer which monkey patches ActiveRecord::Schema.define and doesn't run initialize_schema_migrations_table() or assume_migrated_up_version. The suggestion was to uninstall the gem then run db:schema:load again, but not sure which gem or if it would mess up something else in the process.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please refer to this https://github.com/ankane/ahoy

Comment: @kishorecheruku I don't think this monkeypatch is actually part of the gem. I have a really hard time seeing why a gem that just implements tracking would monkeypatch a core peice of Rails like this. This smells like a dirty rotten kludge.

Comment: I think we are going to need some more details here - can you follow the trace to that monkeypatch and add it to the question? "The suggestion was to uninstall the gem then run db:schema:load again, but not sure which gem or if it would mess up something else in the process." was that the suggestion by the developer who added the moneypatch? Its hard to say what could break by removing the monkeypatch since we don't know the what or the why behind it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers. e